# Define the width of peak in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to find some peaks in Matlab, but the function `findpeaks.m` doesn't have the width option. The peaks I want to be detected are in the balls. All the detected are in the red squares. As you can see they have a low width. Any help?

[image]

here's the code I use:

```
[pk,lo] = findpeaks(ecg);

lo2 = zeros(size(lo));

for m = 1:length(lo) - 1
    if (ecg(m) - ecg(m+1)) > 0.025
        lo2(m) = lo(m);
    end
end

p = find(lo2 == 0);

lo2(p) = [];

figure, plot(ecg);
hold on
plot(lo, ecg(lo), 'rs');
```

Comment: What is your definition of peak width?
The amount of points around a peak where the graph has a locally maximum value? The smallest interval that contains a local maximum?

Comment: Do you want to make the squares bigger?

Comment: No, i want to detect only the "thinner" peaks.

Comment: I'm lazy to wirte it as an answer with a proper code, but you need to decide the desired gradient you want, and for each point in the red squares (inside the function, no need to get it as a result) you can check the Y-change along some X-change that you defined.

Comment: If you could segment each of the individual peaks of your data into unimodal peaks AND provided that your data has sufficient resolution (or could be interpolated), you could then use [`kurtosis`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kurtosis.html) to obtain a statistical measure of peak width. You'd need to shift each segmented to peak to be centered at zero. [More on kurtosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it you want to characterise each peak in terms of amplitude and width, so that you can apply thresholds (or simmilar) to these values to select only those meeting your criteria (tall and thin).

One way you could do this is to fit a normal distribution to each peak, pegging the mean and amplitude to the value you have found already, and using an optimisation function to find the standard deviation (width of normal distribution).

So, you would need a function which calculates a representation of your data based on the sum of all the gaussian distributions you have, and an error function (mean squared error perhaps) then you just need to throw this into one of matlabs inbuilt optimisation/minimisation functions.

The optimal set of standard deviation parameters would give you the widths of each peak, or at least a good approximation.

Another method, based on Adiel's comment and which is perhaps more appropriate since it looks like you are working on ecg data, would be to also find the local minima (troughs) as well as the peaks. From this you could construct an approximate measure of 'thinness' by taking the x-axis distance between the troughs on either side of a given peak.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a *peak width* first, determine how narrow you want your peaks to be and  then select them accordingly.

For instance, you can define the width of a peak as the difference between the x-coordinates at which the y-coordinates equal to half of the peak's value (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_width_at_half_maximum)). Another approach, (which seems more appropriate here) is to measure the gradient at fixed distances from the peak itself, and selecting the peaks accordingly. In MATLAB, you'll probably use a gradient filter for that :

```
g = conv(ecg, [-1 0 1], 'same'); %// Gradient filter
idx = g(lo) > thr);              %// Indices of narrow peaks
lo = lo(idx);
```

where `thr` is the threshold value that you need to determine for yourself. Lower threshold values mean more tolerance for wider peaks.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking pragmatically, I suppose you could use something along the lines of this simple brute-force approach:

```
[peaks  , peakLocations]   = findpeaks(+X);
[troughs, troughLocations] = findpeaks(-X);

width = zeros(size(peaks));
for ii = 1:numel(peaks)

    trough_before = troughLocations( ...
        find(troughLocations < peakLocations(ii), 1,'last') );

    trough_after  = troughLocations( ...
        find(troughLocations > peakLocations(ii), 1,'first') );

    width(ii) = trough_after - trough_before;

end
```

This will find the distance between the two troughs surrounding a peak of interest.

Use the `'MinPeakHeight'` option in `findpeaks()` to pre-prune your data. By the looks of it, there is no *automatic* way to extract the peaks you want (unless you somehow have explicit indices to them). Meaning, you'll have to select them manually.

Now of course, there will be many more details that will have to be dealt with, but given the shape of your data set, I think the underlying idea here can nicely solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define what it means to be a peak of interest, and what you mean by the width of that peak. Once you do those things, you are a step ahead.

Perhaps you might locate each peak using find peaks. Then locate the troughs, one of which should lie between each pair of peaks. A trough is simply a peak of -y. Make sure you worry about the first and last peaks/troughs.

Next, define the half height points as the location midway in height between each peak and trough. This can be done using a reverse linear interpolation on the curve.

Finally, the width at half height might be simply the distance (on the x axis) between those two half height points.